# How to compile Android licensing sample. No libraries, only source

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have downloaded licensing package in SDK.
There are no libraries (LVL ?), only source code in play_licensing/library.
I don't know how to compile their sample and my app. with their library source code.
No rules there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the source code into the source folder in your Android project, and compile it that way.